# Is there any method to append path to environment variable 'PATH' in python

Tags: python

I want to append the path to exists environment variable PATH using python script.

I have tried to use `os.environ['path'] = 'C:\foo\bin:%PATH%'`, but its deleting all the existing paths and creating 
`'C:\foo\bin:%PATH%'` as new path value.

```
os.environ['path'] = 'C:\foo\bin:%PATH%'
```

Comment: Do you want your chances to be presistent when the script has finished running?

Comment: Is it a file or a folder?

Comment: @moeassal... I want to add multiple bin from different folders and some folders

Comment: @ I want those environment variables temperorly

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to modify `os.environ`.

Since `os.pathsep` is the character to separate different paths, you should use this to append each new path:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path
```

or, if there are several paths to add in a list:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join(pathlist)
```

As you mentioned, `os.path.join` can also be used for each individual path you have to append in the case you have to construct them from separate parts.

Answer (score 5):

You should be doing

```
  import os

  os.environ["PATH"] = "/your/path/"+ os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would want or even need to insert the new path at the front?

Comment: it is normally good to append it at the front so that in case there is another binary with the same name in `os.environ["PATH"]`, the one in `/your/path/` will take precedence.  the lookup happens from left to right

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
os.environ['path'] = 'C:\foo\bin:%PATH%
```

`python` does not know what to do with `%PATH%` in the string, but the old value of the `PATH` environment variable is accessible as `os.environ['path']`, so you can simply do:

```
os.environ['path'] = 'C:\foo\bin;' + os.environ['path']
```